# How to use particular language keyboard in java

Tags: java, keyboard

I am doing an application in the swing in which I have to input in Marathi, I have installed Google input tool but each time I required to change input keyboard.

I searched over but not found any solution, is there any way to set keyboard or set particular input language to the text field or any input field.

```
jTextField1.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("he","IL"));
```

I used this but not works for me.

Comment: Are you changing *physical* keyboards?  Also, do you mean that the `selectInputMethod()` approach *does not* work for you?

Comment: no. I have to change google input keyboard or get input in given language.